On an estimate in the paper by Donnelly and Fefferman
I was reading the following paper by Donnelly and Fefferman https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01393691.pdf which essentially deals with the Hausdorff dimension bound of the nodal sets where the metric is analytic.
Now if the metric $g$ is $C^{\infty}$ say, and $(M,g)$ is a closed Riemannian manifold and $u$ be a Laplace eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then for any ball $B\subset M$ they proved using Carleman type estimates that
$\sup_{\frac{1}{2}B}|u|\geq c\exp^{-C\sqrt{\lambda}}\sup_{B}|u|$
I am just curious to know whether the same kind of estimates hold true for Bi-Laplacian or $p$-Laplace eigenfunctions. If not, then is there some weaker estimate than this is known or any counterexample?
